# get matching value from other column/dataframe using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe
[image: a=]

output :

[image]

How to get this out put using pandas I tried using groupby but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this `df["dscription"] = df[["id"]].merge(df[["pid", "description"]], left_on="id", right_on="pid", how="left")["description"]`